# How to fix "Predis \ Response \ ServerException ERR syntax error"?

Tags: laravel, redis

It seems that my redis server is not working,anybody how to fix this?
Thank you in advance

```php
public static function getActiveUser($len = 10)
    {
        $key = config('rket.active_key');
        $users = Redis::zrevrange($key, 0, $len, 'WITHSOCRES');
        if (empty($users)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $users;
    }
```

this is where the problem happened.

Comment: please post more error message.

Answer (score -1):

'ServerException' means something was wrong on the server or the connection to the server. Check if redis server is running or not and also check if your redis configuration is correct.